# Flutter Firebase Firestore Collection snapshot cannot find any documents when there clearly is one

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to list out all documents of a collection and, for some reason, it does not find any when there clearly is one.

Here is the structure of my database:
[image: Firebase Firestore Database Structure Screenshot]

And here is my code:

```dart
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> historySnap = await firebaseManager.db
        .collection("test_history")
        .get();
log(historySnap.size.toString());
```

The above code prints out "0", when it should be "1".

However, in another method, I have this code:

```dart
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> docSnap = await firebaseManager.db
        .collection("test_history")
        .doc("driverslicense_exam")
        .collection("jules")
        .get();
log(docSnap.size.toString());
```

And it perfectly reads the path and gets the documents of the "jules" collection. Am I missing something?

Comment: If the document name is showing in italic, there is actually no document there - and the Firestore console just shows that ID because there is a subcollection with data in it. Since `get()` only gets actual documents, it correctly doesn't return this ID - as there is no document.

Comment: The console should also contain a message in the area that would display the fields for this document explaining this behavior: "This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots. [Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents)"

Comment: I see, may I ask how can I list all entries that *have* subcollections in them? As the italicized documents in the collection doesn't have fields and only subcollections and I have no need to put any fields in.

Comment: Collections do not exist.  https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/firestore-documents  Lots of developers ask about ways to "list subcollections", but the reality is that it is YOUR CODE that created the Documents at different sub/collections, so YOUR CODE likely knows what exists (or could exist).  If you do a web search for "firestore list subcollections" you will see a lot of articles on the subject....and most of them end up resulting in:  You Likely Don't Need (nor want) This Capability.